# mongoDB subdocument match where elemMatch is not object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a subdocument with a schema like the following

```
{
    things: [ { thing: { type: String }, otherThing: { type: String } ]
}
```

Let's pretend it's populated like so

```
[
    { thing: 'Thing 1', otherThing: '123-001'},
    { thing: 'Thing 2', otherThing: '123-002'},
    { thing: 'Thing 3', otherThing: '123-003'},
    { thing: 'Thing 4', otherThing: '123-004'}
]
```

I want to now insert into this Thing 5, but I want to check if it exists first, so I do:

```
Things.findOneAndUpdate(
{ 
  things: {
    $elemMatch: {
      thing: {
        $ne: 'Thing 5'
      }
    }
  }
}, 
{ 
  $push: { 
    things : { 
      thing: 'Thing 5', 
      otherThing: '123-005'
    }
  }
})
```

When I run the script the first time, Thing 5 gets inserted. When I run it the second time, I expect it to fail, but it inserts a duplicate "Thing 5".

I suspect this is because $elemMatch thing $ne matches Thing 1 - 4 and therefore will push. What do I need to do so it basically says "if Thing 5 isn't inside any of these subdocuments"?

Comment: Why not just use `{ "things.thing":{$ne:"thing5"} }` ?

Comment: As per mongo doc it should be like things: {
    thing: {
      $elemMatch: {
        $ne: 'Thing 5'
      }
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

As @Veeram pointed out, use dot notaion instead and it works.

This code works for me on mongo:

```
db.col.update({ "things.thing":{$ne:"Thing 5"} }, {$push:{things:{'thing': 'Thing 5', 'otherThing': '123-005'}}})
```

Useful link to dot notation:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation

Hope it helps